# Arch linux - sound disappeared after the installation of pulseaudio

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, alsa, pulse-audio

I'm using Arch linux with the above onboard sound card :

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0220
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at dfdfc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Few days ago i needed skype for a call but sound in skype didn't worked (microphone and headphones). So i installed pulse audio and everything worked out properly.

The day after pulse audio installation, i went to youtube to hear something but no sound came out. I run the `pauvcontrol` and everything seemed to work while the sound meter was moving and everything was un-muted.

Then i run `alsamixer`, and once again every channel was un-muted and full.

I couldn't understood where the problem was and decided to remove the pulse audio with `pacman -Rns` command. The bad news is that i still have no sound in the system and i cannot figure out the why. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My audio worked fine until I installed `ardour` (the multitrack audio software. Go figure). This is a `pulseaudio` issue I believe.

I simply gutted my system by `pacman -Rnc` anything `pulse-` related. I rebooted, and I have audio working again.

Tip: `libcanberra` is one of the packages to cascade remove.

This should leave you with a working `ALSA` sound system. I don't recommend this for anyone wishing to continue using `systemd`.